# Can phase angle be larger than 90 for a simple AC RL circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2micky_3uI) lecture, Walter Lewin provides the equation for the phase angle in a simple $RL$ circuit: $$\tan(\phi) = {\omega L\over R}$$

Looking at this equation, it seems to me that no matter how large $\omega$ is, the phase angle cannot exceed $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. So my take on this is that the current cannot lag the voltage by more than $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. I'm pretty sure what I'm saying is  wrong, but I was wondering if someone could explain what I'm missing, or confirm what I'm saying and explain the intuition behind it.

Comment: What is tan(pi)? Maybe we just don't know whether the angle is 0° or 360°.

Comment: For a circuit with just two components, a ideal resistor and an ideal inductor, this is true. However *real* inductors are not ideal and also have capacitance, which means they can form a resonant circuit without any other components. And a *network* of ideal passive components can have a phase shift of anything (including greater than 360 degrees).

Answer (score 1):

First, think about what the phase angle should be for a purely inductive circuit, i.e., $R\rightarrow 0$.

Now, if you think about it, for $R\ne 0$, and $\omega\rightarrow\infty$, the inductive reactance increases without bound while $R$ remains constant.

Wouldn't the intuition be that the two cases should be identical in their limits?

---

From the comments:

> I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're trying to get at. How
>   does this explain the pi over 2 limit on phi?

For the case of a purely inductive AC circuit, the phase angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This follows directly from the governing equation for an ideal inductor:

$$v_L = L\frac{di_L}{dt}$$

For example, stipulate that the current through the inductor is $i_L = I_0\sin(\omega t)$. The voltage across the inductor is then

$$v_L = \omega LI_0\cos(\omega t) = \omega LI_0\sin(\omega t + \pi/2)$$

See that the inductor voltage and current are in quadrature, i.e., the voltage and current are 90 degrees out of phase (in AC steady state).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're trying to get at. How does this explain the pi over 2 limit on phi?

Comment: @user10796158, are you aware that, for a purely inductive AC circuit, the phase angle is $\pi/2$, the voltage and current are 90 degrees out of phase?

Comment: I mean I deduced that from the equation because when R --> 0, we get a pi/2 phase shift. I didn't know that beforehand

Comment: @user10796158, it follows directly from the governing equation:  $v_L = L\frac{di_L}{dt}$. So, for example, if $i_L = I_0\sin(\omega t)$, then $v_L = \omega LI_0\cos(\omega t)$, i.e., the voltage and current are 90 degrees out of phase in AC steady state.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage at across an inductor is given by $V=L\frac {dI}{dt}$ so if the current is a sine function of time then the voltage will be a cosine function of time.
This means that the voltage leads the current by $\frac \pi 2$ or the current lags the voltage by $\frac \pi 2$.
However you could also say that the phase difference is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ etc, ie the current leads the voltage by $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

In simple ac theory the phase angle between current and voltage is chosen to range from $+\frac \pi 2$ to $-\frac \pi 2$.
So the answer to your question is that by convention the phase angle between current and voltage is never larger than $+\frac \pi 2$ and never smaller than $-\frac \pi 2$.